# Cannot select run only applescript

Tags: applescript

When I try to save the file run-only does not show up.  This may be because I am on Big Sur.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Script Editor**, the **Run-only** *option* is available when using: **File** > **Export…**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Big Sur.

You have to **export** the script which makes a lot of sense because *saving* the current script as run-only will make your source code inaccessible.